# OAuth 2.0 Access token is not encrypted?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.jwt library for jwt access token and after i call WriteToken, I can get back the access token value from ReadToken in another program. So the access token is not actually encrypted by default?

Answer (score 0):

Not encrypted, but it should be *signed* so as to prevent tampering.

The [jwt library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.114).aspx) has a `ValidateToken` method to check the token signature is correct using your token signing cert or key.

You would need to rely on SSL for encryption.
[This Blog post](http://www.kahneraja.com/signing-and-encrypting-a-jwt-oauth-token/) gives a bit more detail on the difference between signing and encrypting the token.

If you think it sounds a little crazy for Oauth2.0 to rely on SSL then you wouldn't be alone. Check out [Eran Hammer's thoughts](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/) on Oauth2.0 and why he walked away from it.